# Unable to set values when I Moq Confluent.Kafka.WatermarkOffsets

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have this `Moq` in a `.Net` test which mocks `Confluent.Kafka.WatermarkOffsets`:

```
Mock<WatermarkOffsets> _mockWatermarkOffsets = new Mock<WatermarkOffsets>();
```

In one of my tests I want to set a High and Low value so attempted the following:

I tried `_mockWatermarkOffsets.Object.Low = 1` and `_mockWatermarkOffsets.Object.Low = 10` but it seems they can't be set:

> Gets the offset of the earliest message in the topic/partition. If no messages have been written to the topic, the low watermark offset is set to 0. The low watermark will also be 0 if one message has been written to the partition (with offset 0).
>
> CS0200: Property or indexer cannot be assigned to “--” it is read only

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Apologies. It's been updated.

Comment: Can't you just instantiate a `WatermarkOffsets`? Is there a specific need for actually mocking it?

Comment: No need to mock `WatermarkOffsets`. If there are no negative effects of using an actual instance then use it.

Answer (score 1):

For mocking a property getter, you need to use the `Setup`/`SetupGet` methods in your mocked object:

```
_mockWatermarkOffsets.SetupGet(m => m.Low).Returns(1); // Preferable, to express your intent
_mockWatermarkOffsets.Setup(m => m.Low).Returns(1);
```

However, you can't mock [`WatermarkOffsets.Low`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka/WatermarkOffsets.cs#L58) because it's not marked as `virtual`, therefore `Moq` cannot override it.

Another thing that would get in the way of your mock is the fact that  [`WatermarkOffsets`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka/WatermarkOffsets.cs#L58) does not contain a parameterless constructor. A workaround would be to use the following (ugly) construct to build your mock:

```
var parameters = new object[] { new Offset(1), new Offset(10) };
var mock = new Mock<WatermarkOffsets>(parameters);
```

My suggestion is that your best option here is to simply use a `WatermarkOffsets` instance, as suggested by [Riwen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4317297/riwen)